# Open .zip with Windowsexplorer after Zipping with .NET c#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, zip, windows-explorer

Hey I have a little problem i´am Zipping Files with C# in my RAM and Upload them to an Ftp-Server. Thats work very good.

destinyPath = "product/test/zipped.zip";
sourcePath = @"C:\devtest..."

```
    private String UploadToFtp(String destinyPath, String sourcePath, ref FtpClient client)
    {
        String error = "success";
        try
        {
            // Stream im Arbeitsspeicher erstellen
            using (Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())

            // Ziparchive anhand des verweißes auf den memoryStream erstellen
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                // Dateien im gezippten Ordner bestimmen
                foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourcePath))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry entry;
                    if (path.Length > 248)
                    {
                        // Bestimmte Dateien ins Ziparchive erstellen mit langen Pfad
                        entry = archive.CreateEntry(ZlpPathHelper.GetFileNameFromFilePath(path));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Bestimmte Dateien ins Ziparchive erstellen mit kurzem Pfad
                        entry = archive.CreateEntry(Delimon.Win32.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
                    }

                    // Original Daten (entryStream) in Ziparchivedateien (fileStream) schreiben
                    using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())

                    using (Stream fileStream = Delimon.Win32.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                    }
                }
                //memoryStream curser auf anfang setzen
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //Stream auf den FtpServer laden
            client.RetryAttempts = 3;
                client.Upload(memoryStream, destinyPath);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.ToString();
        }
        return error;
    }
```

But now my problem. If i try to open them with doubleclick after downloading i always get the same excption from Windows: "Can´t open the directory. The Zip directory 'C:*' is invalid." but if i do right click 7-zip->open->*, 7-zip->open-># or 7-zip->open->#:e it works.

properties: open with is the Windows-Explorer.

And yes i tried to download the .zip again and again. I googled and found something like "Cant find the Fileending", but no solving approaches.

Comment: Can you include sample input parameters for this method in the question?

Comment: So has your problem anything to do with FTP? Can you open the ZIP file if you stream it to a local file, instead of FTP?

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use only native .NET classes? I.e. no `ZlpPathHelper` or `Delimon.Win32.IO.File`.

Comment: We need [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I found my misstak. It had nothing to do with ZlpPathHelper or Delimon assemblies.

This is now the Code witch work. i put the using "}{" to the wrong place. The Ftp Upload shouldn´t be in the using block from the archive-Stream.

that has the consequence the .zip archive uploaded before the archive was completely created. => all files are in the archive but it gaves an error if i try to open it.

```
    private String UploadToFtp(String destinyPath, String sourcePath, ref FtpClient client)
    {
        String error = "success";
        try
        {
            // Stream im Arbeitsspeicher erstellen
            using (Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Ziparchive anhand des verweißes auf den memoryStream erstellen
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    // Dateien im gezippten Ordner bestimmen
                    foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourcePath))
                    {
                        ZipArchiveEntry entry;
                        if (path.Length > 248)
                        {
                            // Bestimmte Dateien ins Ziparchive erstellen mit langen Pfad
                            entry = archive.CreateEntry(ZlpPathHelper.GetFileNameFromFilePath(path));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Bestimmte Dateien ins Ziparchive erstellen mit kurzem Pfad
                            entry = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(path));
                        }

                        // Original Daten (entryStream) in Ziparchivedateien (fileStream) schreiben
                        using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            using (Stream fileStream = Delimon.Win32.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
                            {
                                fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //memoryStream curser auf anfang setzen
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //Stream auf den FtpServer laden
                client.RetryAttempts = 3;
                client.Upload(memoryStream, destinyPath);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.ToString();
        }
        return error;
    }
```